# Mount device as RW for root and RO for everyone else

Tags: permissions, mount, fstab, read-only

I have a device I want to mount for root with full permissions and for everyone else as readonly. The man page tells me this is possible.

So:

- `sudo mkdir /mnt/foo`
- `sudo mkdir /mnt/fooReadOnly`
- `sudo chmod 700 /mnt/foo` (rw for root only)
- `sudo chmod 444 /mnt/fooReadOnly` (ro for everyone)
- ensure device `/dev/sdaX` is mounted as `/mnt/foo`

Then I did what the man page suggested:

- `sudo mount --bind /mnt/foo /mnt/fooReadOnly`
- `sudo mount -o remount,bind,ro /mnt/foo /mnt/fooReadOnly`

Now to test:

- `ls /mnt/foo` --> `Permission denied` ...**CORRECT**
- `sudo ls /mnt/foo` works ..**CORRECT**
- `ls /mnt/fooReadOnly` --> `Permission denied` ...**INCORRECT?**

How do I fix this?

Also, how do I add this to `/etc/fstab` so that it will automatically remount on boot?

Comment: You will need 555 permissions on the directory to be able to traverse it. Why don't you look at ACLs instead ?

Comment: @solsTiCe I can't change anything for that bind mount, it says: `chmod: changing permissions of '/mnt/fooReadOnly/': Read-only file system`. Thing is according to the man pages, this functionality is actually supposed to work, so I'm obviously doing something wrong.

Comment: "I have a device", what sort of device? In particular, which filesystem?

Comment: @fkraiem ext4 hard drive

Comment: Normally, permissions on ext4 drives are managed by using `chown`/`chmod`on the actual files...

Comment: @fkraiem Not in this case, we're not talking about the files - the entire mount cannot be accessed, which goes against the expected functionality. The man pages specifically say that what I want to do is possible, and even lists the commands I've typed above. But it doesn't work for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

First, unmount fooReadOnly with
`sudo umount /mnt/fooReadOnly`

Then, change the permission of fooReadOnly to 555
`sudo chmod 555 /mnt/fooReadOnly`
This is needed because entering a directory requires execute privilege.

Finally, remount fooReadOnly
`sudo mount -o remount,bind,ro /mnt/foo /mnt/fooReadOnly`

Comment: Doesn't work. Before mounting, the permissions work as expected, but after the bind mounting they are are automatically set to `drwx------`.

Comment: Did you try chmod after mounting?

Comment: yes, it's a readonly volume, so nothing can be changed